# "dimension too large" error when broadcasting to sparse matrix in octave

Tags: octave

32-bit Octave has a limit on the maximum number of elements in an array.  I have recompiled from source (following the script at https://github.com/calaba/octave-3.8.2-enable-64-ubuntu-14.04 ), and now have 64-bit indexing.

Nevertheless, when I attempt to perform elementwise multiplication using a broadcast function, I get `error: out of memory or dimension too large for Octave's index type`

Is this a bug, or an undocumented feature?  If it's a bug, does anyone have a reasonably efficient workaround?

Minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
function indexerror();
% both of these are formed without error
%    a = zeros (2^32, 1, 'int8');
%    b = zeros (1024*1024*1024*3, 1, 'int8');

%   sizemax    % returns 9223372036854775806

    nnz = 1000            % number of non-zero elements
    rowmax = 250000
    colmax = 100000

    irow = zeros(1,nnz);
    icol = zeros(1,nnz);
    for ind =1:nnz
        irow(ind) = round(rowmax/nnz*ind);
        icol(ind) = round(colmax/nnz*ind);
    end

    sparseMat = sparse(irow,icol,1,rowmax,colmax);

    % column vector to be broadcast
    broad = 1:rowmax;
    broad = broad(:);

    % this gives "dimension too large" error
    toobig = bsxfun(@times,sparseMat,broad);

    % so does this
    toobig2 = sparse(repmat(broad,1,size(sparseMat,2)));
    mult = sparse( sparseMat .* toobig2 );        % never made it this far
end
```

**EDIT:**
Well, I have an *inefficient* workaround.  It's slower than using `bsxfun` by a factor of 3 or so (depending on the details), but it's better than having to sort through the error in the libraries. Hope someone finds this useful some day.

```
% loop over rows, instead of using bsxfun
mult_loop = sparse([],[],[],rowmax,colmax);
for ind =1:length(broad);
    mult_loop(ind,:) = broad(ind) * sparseMat(ind,:);
end
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the new [octave broadcasting mechanism](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Broadcasting.html) : `toobig = sparseMat .* rep;` ?

Comment: Just tried it, but that also gives an error:
`product: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 250000x100000, op2 is 250000x1)`

Comment: It ought to work. This seems related to [bug 35787](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?35787)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The unfortunate answer is that yes, this is a bug.  Apparently `@bsxfun` and `repmat` are returning full matrices rather than sparse.  Bug has been filed here:
http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47175